# Give global variable own cache line

Tags: c

I want to place a static global variable (32-bit integer) in its own cache line in a C program (and I also want to do this for an extern global variable). What is the best way to do this? Should I define the global in a struct and pad the struct? The align directive is ignored by the compiler.

This is to improve performance since the global is used by one thread and there are other variables defined above and below it that are used by other threads on other physical cores. I'd prefer not to create structs but I am not sure how to do this otherwise. I am using GCC 7.4.1 and am compiling for AArch64.

Comment: static global or extern global?

Comment: @Jasen In this case it's a static global, but I would appreciate if you could answer for both.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Please edit the information in your previous response to a comment into the question.  Also add details of the o/s and compiler.  What you’re seeking to do is unusual and I’d remain to be convinced of its efficacy. It is inherently platform specific.

Comment: for an extern I would use assembler, I don't have an answer for static

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks I added this information. I am writing a high-performance network application with DPDK. Different cores are using global variables in a loop and I don't want to have false sharing.

Comment: "Different cores are using global variables in a loop..."  That rather sounds like something that shouldn't be in cache at all. Since you'll need some means of thread-safety protection, you'll end up with some manner of memory barriers. So it really sounds as if "give global variable own cache line" is the wrong solution to a different problem than the one you have. Instead look for ways to minimize shared variables and critical sections.

Comment: If you're on a Unix system and are willing to go via a pointer, there is `posix_memalign`.

Answer (score 0):

You just **can't** place things in cache line manually using only C (as I suspect from the tags). Note that some variables can't be placed there (eg. ones with `volatile` modifier); there is no *portable* way to accomplish such thing.